# Invalid hex escape

Tags: ruby, string, hex

There is my code :

```
var = "aa"
var2 = "bb"
var3 = "\x#{var}\x#{var2}"
```

And I want the "var3" to be hexadecimal.

But the error message is "Invalid hex escape". How can I fix that ?

Comment: You want `var3` to be what? Please specify explicitly what output do you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could help:

```
var3 = "#{var.hex.chr}#{var2.hex.chr}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work because `\x` has “higher priority” than string interpolation.

```
vars = [var, var2]
var3 = vars.pack('H*' * vars.size)
#⇒ "\xAA\xBB"
```

[More info](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-pack).

Comment: The `.hex.chr` solution works, but this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is this:

```
[var, var2].map { |s| '\x' + s }.join
```

Can you explain why you want var3 to be in that format?  If it's to serialize the values, then another method might be simpler, e.g.:

```
require 'yaml'
[var, var2].to_yaml
# or
{ var: var, var2: var2 }.to_yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to send epoch timestamp as raw hexadecimal code, idea is simple create an array of bytes and then "pack" it (this will encode the string in the right way so it can be read and decode as hex code)

```
epoch_timestamp = 1631737774
epoch_hex = epoch_timestamp.to_s(16)
# epoch_hex is 4 bytes 614257a6
bytes = [epoch_hex[0..1], epoch_hex[2..3], epoch_hex[4..5], epoch_hex[6..7]]
bytes.pack('H*' * bytes.size)
```